# ConcurrentModificationException: single thread, two different Hashtables

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I'm getting a ConcurrentModificationException CME that seems to differ from the cases asked for in other threads.  I'm running a single thread only. Here's my code piece (edited):

```
for(Type t : other.types.values()) {
    types.put(t.getName(), t)
}
```

The CME occurs in the `for` statement.  `types` is of type `Hashtable<String, Type>` and is a non-static member variable in an object of type `Obj`.  `other` is of type `Obj`, too, and the code piece is part of a method of `Obj`.  Just before the `for` loop, I check that `this` and `other`, `this.types` and `other.types`, as well as `this.types.values()` and `other.types.values()` are pairwise different objects.  (Also verified by different object ids in the Eclipse debugger).

The CME is reproducable. I have no clue how it can happen in this situation.

@Edit: The code piece comes from a larger tool, which actually supports multi-threading. The number of threads is controllable and this issue occurs when selecting a single thread only.  Also in its method, the code is surrounded by two synchronizations: one on `types` and the other on `other.types`. So, I guess, it's not a threading problem.

The tool runs on Windows and Linux. We use Java 1.7 with 1.6 compatibility level. 
(Sorry for the bad code, it's not mine)

Comment: I tested and I cannot reproduce this behavior, show more code around your snippet. Btw, how do you know you're running a single thread only? Are you using any libraries (Swing, GWT...)? Where are you running this (Windows, Android...)?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the javadoc of [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
>   For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

As you are using a [foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) you are actually using an [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to navigate over the elements of the collection. Typically the implementations of Iterator are throwing the mentioned exception if you are modifying the underlying collection after the creation of the iterator - in your case, the iterator is creator on the first iteration over the collection. The issue is avoidable by using the "classic" for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i< other.types.values().size(); i++) {
    types.put(t.getName(), t)
}
```

Nevertheless I presume you are trying to add all elements from `other.types` to `types`, for that you can simply do:

```
types.putAll(other.types)
```

If the two are maps.

Comment: Your solution is definitely advisable. However the fact that he explicitly checks that this.types != other.types should actually avoid a concurrent modification, since he wouldn't change the underlying collection. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Chnoch - sorry, but I don't think I understand why the explicit check would help with the concurrent modification exception. Could you please emphasize?

Comment: Because he iterates over other.types and adds new items to this.types. The way I see it other.types isn't being modified at all. If other.types and types were the same reference it would be obvious, but since he checks for object equality they should be different HashMaps and therefore other.types isn't modified if he just adds new elements to types.